# html | Extra tabs in textarea

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'm trying to load markdown from my database to a textarea:

```
<textarea class="wmd-input" id="wmd-input" name="question" required="required"> 
<?php echo '**This is a header**    1. List 2. List 3. List ----------'; ?>
</textarea>
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function () {
        var qa_converter = Markdown.getSanitizingConverter();
        var qa_editor = new Markdown.Editor(qa_converter);
        qa_editor.run();
    })();
</script>
```

And as you can see on the picture I have broken first line (extra tabs at the beginning of string).

[image]

I'm using this markdown editor: https://code.google.com/p/pagedown/

Where is a problem?

Comment: Try and add a line break in betwwen eg (<?php echo '**This is a header** <br /> ...) or if that doesnt work and you see the <br /> in the text area try (<?php echo '**This is a header** \n ...)

Comment: Sorry. Not working...

Comment: It was a long-shot. There's an answer for you.

Comment: you see, i knew the issue was a line break. :))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try writing the following in one line:

```
<textarea class="wmd-input" id="wmd-input" name="question" required="required"><?php echo '**This is a header**    1. List 2. List 3. List ----------'; ?></textarea>
```

Comment: glad to be helpful :)